# Configure multiple backends with Azure Front Door using paths

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

Currently I have xyz.azurefd.net and am having a bit of trouble configuring it correctly.
I have two backends: frontend1 and frontend2

I want to configure an endpoints so that xyz.azurefd.net/frontend1 points to frontend1 and xyz.azurefd.net/frontend2 points to frontend2.

Some other considerations, when I normally hit frontend1 it appends a path /abc so it looks like frontend1.com/abc/*

How can I configure my azure front door to do the above behavior?

PS.

> I set up my route with patterns to match: /frontend1/* My endpoint is
> xyz.azurefd.net My backend points to an azure web app However when I
> go to https://xyz.azurefd.net/frontend1/
>
> I get a 404 error.
>
> If I set my patterns to match: /* And go to https://xyz.azurefd.net/
> It sends me to https://xyz.azurefd.net/PATH/PATH1/PATH2 as a default
> path.
>
> I think the reason I am getting a 404 possibly could be due to the
> react application that is being served. It may be that when I use the
> path /frontend1/* to redirect to my application, my application might
> be reading the /frontend1/ as a path causing it to 404. How can I make
> this setup work where the path /frontend1/ will be my base path so
> when I go to it I can visit
> https://xyz.azurefd.net/frontend1/PATH/PATH1/PATH2/

Answer (score 0):

> Configure multiple backends with Azure Front Door using paths

***You can define routing rules that specify which backend to use based on the request's URL path. For example, you can route requests to `/api` to one backend and requests to `/images` to another backend.***

- Front Door allows you to define frontend hosts, which are the public-facing endpoints through which clients access your application.

**Front door and CDN<myfirstfd<settings<front door manager<your-routes.**

[image]

Here you can find the below configuration options add your path below.

[image]

Once the setup is done, just refresh your FD and route. Then I can be able to route `/frontend1`.

[image]

These my frontend applications (1,2) & Origin type is app service.

[image]

***Frontendapp01:***
[image]

***Frontendapp02:***
[image]